# matplot axis issues start from 0 instead of 1

Tags: matplotlib

```
history = model.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=5,
                batch_size=300,
                validation_split= 0.2)

# Plot history: Categorical crossentropy & Accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Loss (training data)')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Loss (validation data)')
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='Accuracy (training data)')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='Accuracy (validation data)')
plt.title('Model performance')
plt.ylabel('Loss value')
plt.xlabel('No. epoch')
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()

# Plot history: Categorical crossentropy & Accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Loss (training data)')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Loss (validation data)')

plt.title('Model performance')
plt.ylabel('Loss value')
plt.xlabel('No. epoch')
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

The plot generates a value starting from epoch 0 on x axis mapping its corresponding y value along y axis. However , the x value should start from 1 instead of 0 , so how do i shift the whole graph rightwards by 1 but at the same time show the whole graph from x axis range of 0 to 5, 0 being empty. Values from range 1-5 epoch instead of 0-4.

Answer (score 0):

So basically the problem is with x axis starting from 0 and you want it to start by 1.. Just add this before the `plt.show()` statement

```
plt.xticks(x_train) #basically pass the list which contains the values you want on the x axis.
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: hi , thanks , after adding that , another error popped out                                                 -->plt.xticks(x_train)                                                                                              ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Hi and for x axis , I am looking for validation loss and loss , thus i think should be something like this plt.xticks(history['loss']))

Comment: Yeah! As I mentioned in the comment, `plt.xticks(list)` this list contains all the values you want as label on the x axis.

Comment: I wasn't having an idea about what you wanted as labels and the `x_train` seemed the most logical one so I chose that..

Comment: hi Ayush , this code merely made changes to the x axis , what I am looking for is to shift the whole graph rightwards by adding 1 , such that the value of y axis at x =0 is not shifted to x =1 , epochs of 5 for x axis is 1,2,3,4,5 instead of 0,1,2,3,4. Thanks for the help earlier , are u able to advise on this one?

Comment: Hi Tonz!! I am not able to understand your requirement, it would be great if you could add a sample output to your question.